# C++ lazy evaluation of boolean or in function call expression

Tags: c++, lazy-evaluation

Quick question, in c++ is this expression lazily evaluated?

```
bool funca();
bool funcb();

funca() || funcb(); // line in question
```

Obviously this is (potentially) just shorthand for the following:

```
bool funca();
bool funcb();

if (!funca()) {
    funcb();
}

// or even more concisely:

if (!funca()) funcb();
```

Will c++ evaluate that original line in question as I'm hoping it will? Thanks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In C/C++ the logical operators short-circuit. In `a || b` if `a` is true `b` is not evaluated and in `a && b` if `a` is false `b` is not evaluated.

Careful: this only happens with `&&` and `||`, not with `|` and `&`.

Answer (score 9):

It's called a [short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). But, yes - it's lazy, with respect to "||", in that if the condition must evaluate to true then it stops (e.g. if (a || b) will not evaluate b if a is true). And similarly with "&&" in that if (a && b) where a is false b is not evaluated.

Comment: What's the difference between short ciruit eval and lazy eval... wasn't so clear to me with my research.

Comment: Given `c = (a || b);` a properly lazy eval wouldn't determine if `a` or `b` is true until `c` is actually used. In C++ the compiler might move the assignment to just before `c` is accessed and effectively have that behavior, but nothing requires it.

Answer (score 5):

No. Lazy evaluation means that an subexpression is evaluated only when the expression in which it is contained is needed. Since you discard the result of the full expression, lazy evaluation would evaluate **nothing**.

If you had written `writeBoolean(funcA() || funcB());` lazy evaluation would have evaluated funcA() since that's definitely necessary,  and possibly funcB.

But that's not how C++ works; C++ does not have lazy evaluation. Even if you discard the result of an expression, it's still evaluated. You **do** get short-circuit evaluation. Whether `funcB` is called does not depend on use of the full expression, but it does depend on the result of `funcA`.